# Parsing the code number of each row for a specific keyword

Tags: matlab, parsing, text

My problem is that I want to read a text file from a specific link, but I found it quite difficult.

First, my text file is organized as follows:

```
h20198988    book, old book, new book
h20887878    computer, machine, new machine,
```

My task is to find a particular word in the entire text file and return the number corresponding to that word as an output.

I know that I can use `regexp` or `strtok` to find a word?

Comment: What are your problems? What is the format you want to use?

Comment: @Floris, thank you for the reply,  
filepath{k}=fullfile(imgpath,T_MODE,keyword,strcat('img_',num2str(count_save),'.jpg');
I have im=imread (im)
I want to replace the imwrite(im,filepath{k}); with another ways of saving to a file. Any idea

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `imwrite` to save these JPEGs. Please clarify your question, rather than filling the comments with code. Do you get an error? What is the full error message? Otherwise please explain exactly what you need that `imwrite` can't do.

Comment: @horchler, I have mutliple images parsed from a link, the imwrite doesnt save all of them, only save small portion. any explanation is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you show an exact piece of code that fails, and when it fails (edit your question, don't add a comment)? If it works once, it should work many times; it is not likely that the `imwrite` function itself is at fault, but that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Floris my question is edited, Thank you

Comment: You do realize that `%20` is the space, not the `+` symbol… It may not be your problem, but the ASCII code for `+` is `0x2B` so you want to use `%2B` as your `replace` variable...

Comment: That is not a problem @Floris, it works fine but imwrite only save a few images and ignore the remaining. even if i replace it with a '+'.

Comment: Can you prove to yourself (and me) that you are getting all the links to the images correctly, and that you are able to read them in? In other word, display the name of each image, fetch it into memory, and display it - but don't write it. Does that go all the way through the loop? I worry a bit about the way you read in blocks of 16, but I can't test your code right now so it may be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at earlier (and possibly related) questions you posted, it seems like you are simply copying the file from one location to another. You can make life much simpler for yourself by never "knowing" it is an image file at all. If you never convert the file, it will be faster, and when you treat it as a binary file you can just use `fread` and `fwrite` for file I/O:

```
filepath{k}=fullfile(imgpath,T_MODE,keyword,strcat('img_',num2str(count_save),'.‌​jpg');

fin = fopen(fileSource, 'rb');
temp = fread(fileSource);
fclose(fin);

fout = fopen(filepath{k}, 'wb');
fwrite(fout, temp);
fclose(fout);
```

This does not explain why you are having trouble with `imwrite` - you haven't explained why it is not working for you. I do worry a little bit about the strange things you are doing with the `fullfile` function; are you sure the directory you are writing to exists? You might want to do instead:

```
filedir = fullfile(imgpath,T_MODE,keyword);

… test for existence of fielder

filename = fullfile(filedir, sprintf("img_%03d.jpg', count_save);
```

The advantage of this is 1) slightly faster (you do most of the concatenation only once), 2) a chance to test for existence of directory before writing to it, and 3) you have better control over the formatting of the name (using `%03d` means you get `001.jpg`, `002.jpg` etc - which will keep things in proper order. Otherwise, they show up as (e.g.)  `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5` because directory listings tend to be lexical (alphabetical). )